# How to record user voice with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, voice

Save the voice as soundn.wav

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript won't be able to get access to any microphones or other devices that might be attached to the computer, but you definitely can using Flash.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is good, but it's not that good!

jQuery is just not the right tool for that sort of task, neither is Javascript really.  Flash might be a better option if you're working on a web based application.

On Windows you could maybe use Javascript directly in the Windows Scripting host and possibly access a COM library that provides voice recording.

Comment: +1 for "jQuery is good, but it's not that good!"

Comment: @Robin, I heard jQuery will solve the global financial crisis too ;)

Comment: @Ash I think thats a job for Prototype not jQuery :-)

Comment: jQuery is Javascript, thus `jQuery is just not the right tool for that sort of task, neither is Javascript really` is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following two plugins, i found handy for the purpose.

1. [cykod/ FlashWavrecorder](http://cykod.github.com/FlashWavRecorder/html/)
2. [jRecorder](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery)

Althouh, my response is too late to help you solve your problem, but it may help others to find the solution.